# Using Select Box to Update Display Query

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I am just learning Ajax and am trying to update a mysql select query to filter results.  I think the query is working fine, but not sure that I have the event working correctly.

Here is my HTML with the selection;

```
          <div class="volunteers">
            <h1>Volunteers</h1>
            <div class="volunteerSelection">
                <select id="vtSelect" name="volunteerS">
                    <option value="1">Comittee</option>
                    <option value="2">Day of Event</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div id="volunteers">
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is the script that displays the data;

I have updated this to the suggestion and it works fine.  Then I started working on my PHP and mysql query.  See below;

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#vtSelect').change(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var selectedOption = $(this).find('option:selected');
                $('#vtSelect option').removeAttr('selected');
                $(selectedOption).attr('selected', 'selected');
                var selectedOptionValue = $(selectedOption).val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "includes/backDataProcess.php",
                    data: {
                        data: selectedOptionValue
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#volunteers").html(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

This is the PHP with the select query;  I have update this and am getting data.  I updated the name in the select tag, but I am not getting the select tag value in the query.  When I comment out the post data and just fill in a value it posts fine.  I am not getting any errors, it is just displaying 0 results.

```
        <?php
        include('readerConnect.php');
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM contacts prc
        JOIN states as st
        ON (prc.stateId = st.idStates)
        INNER JOIN volunteers as v 
        ON (prc.idContacts = v.contactId)
        INNER JOIN volunteerType as vt 
        ON (v.volunteerTypeId = vt.idVolunteerType)
        WHERE (volunteerTypeId = 1 /*`mysql_real_escape_string('$_POST[volunteerS]')`*/)";

        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo  
                "<div class='contacts'>
                <div class='contactName'>" . $row["firstName"] ." " . $row["lastName"] ."</div>"
                ."<div class='contactAddress'>" .$row["address1"] ." " .$row["address2"] ."<br>"
                .$row["city"] ." " .$row["state"] ." " .$row["zip"] ."</div>"
                ."<div class='contactVolunteer'>" .$row["volunteerTypeId"]
                ."</div>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }
        $conn->close();
        ?>
```

I am not sure exactly where the issue is, I have tried both change and onchange to update, do I need an update button? I thought jquery would be able to do this with no update.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You haven't told us what the error is. You said that you're not sure if the event is working correctly, but it would be helpful to also describe the behaviour or errors you're seeing.

Comment: it isn't displaying any data at all.  I can change it to display all data but using the selection box is not displaying any data at all nor any error.

Answer (score 0):

There are several obvious problems in your jQuery code. If you open your browser console you should see error `onChange is not a function` since there is no such jQuery method. You want `change()` or `on()`

Also you create a function `showVolunteers()` but it never gets called.

try:

```
$('#vtSelect').change(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var selectedOption = $(this).find('option:selected');
    $('#vtSelect option').removeAttr('selected');
    $(selectedOption).attr('selected', 'selected');
    var selectedOptionValue = $(selectedOption).val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "includes/backDataProcess.php",
        data: {
            data: selectedOptionValue
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#volunteers").html(data);
        }
    });

});
```

Should you encounter more problems, use browser console network tab to inspect ajax request, and always use console to check for errors

Comment: Thanks this was a confusing part for me.  I was using the function earlier to display all data and didn't take it out.  I have updated my question with new code for some corrections, almost there I think I am having  problems with passing the post variable to the query.

Comment: you are sending a key named `data` but looking for `$_POST[volunteerS]`. They need to match. Should be evident in browser console when you inspect request and look at what is sent

Comment: I have tried it as `WHERE (volunteerTypeId = `mysql_real_escape_string('$_POST[selectedOptionValue]')`)`  it still doesn't return anything other that 0 results.

Comment: please inspect requests! You aren't sending any post key named `selectedOptionValue`. Your browser will show you exactly what key/value pairs are sent. So would a dump of `$_POST` in php which you can also see in console

Comment: Yes i understand I have looked at that.  It shows me that I am sending data=1 or data=2 depending on the selection.  does this mean I am not sending just a 1 or 2, but the additional information data=?

Comment: Yes, it is exactly the same as sending a form, you send key/value pairs. You should really study some tutorials on this

Comment: Ok I have it figured out.  I create a php variable of the key/value pair like;`$selectionValue = $_POST['dataSelect'];`  Then I pass that value like `WHERE (volunteerTypeId ='" .$selectionValue."')`  This gives the actual data that is the same as what is held in the database.  Next I need to add the mysql real escape string then it should work well thanks for the help.